# LVM Resizing in a Virtual Environment

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, ubuntu-16.04

I have a VM on my local machine (Ubunut 16.04.2 server), utilizing LVM for the main system partitions
Structured as such total launched disk size of 40G (+/-)

```
/boot 500MB XFS

LVM
    /dev/mylvmgroup/system 20GB XFS
    /dev/mylvmgroup/home 15.5G XFS
    /dev/mylvmgroup/swap 4GB swap
```

I have resized the disk to 80G (+/-) and need to add this extra space to `/dev/mylvmgroup/home` so I tried the ol' `xfs_growfs /dev/mylvmgroup/home` and while it does not error out on me, it also does not resize with the extra space

I then thought that I would need to "extend" my lv with `lvextend -L+40G /dev/mylvmgroup/home` however this fails, with `Insufficient free space: 10238 extents needed, but only 0 available`

**NOTE:** I did not add this as an extra disk, I merely resized the existing disk from 40G to 80G

So, how can I add the extra 40G to my existing `/dev/mylvmgroup/home` ??

If I add the extra 40G as a seperate disk, I can simply add it to the group, then extend, then resize (which all works fine), however, that is not what I am after here...

MORE INFO

`fdisk /dev/xvda`   Shows

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/xvda: 80 GiB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdb24217f

Device     Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/xvda1 *      2048   976895   974848  476M 83 Linux
/dev/xvda2      978942 83884031 82905090 39.5G  5 Extended
/dev/xvda5      978944 83884031 82905088 39.5G 8e Linux LVM

Command (m for help): F
Unpartitioned space /dev/xvda: 40 GiB, 42950721536 bytes, 83888128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

   Start       End  Sectors Size
83884032 167772159 83888128  40G
```

Comment: If this is KVM you might want to look at this question https://serverfault.com/questions/839432/kvm-guest-doesnt-recognize-new-size-of-raw-disk-after-lvresize/839444#839444

Comment: Unfortunately it's not.   It's a VMWare box running on a Windows 10 host

Comment: I think I need to recreate the /dev/xvda2 & 5 partitions

Comment: Yeah, that didnt work either.   I recreated the partitions using the entire space of the new size, rebooted the machine, still no extra space.  However, when I `fdisk` the partition `F` no longer shows the 40G free...  hmmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this wasnt as easy as I thought it would be.  Normally, I would just "add" a new volume of a specific size to the instance, add it to my volume group, and extend one of my logical volumes.

This time, I simple launched my new instance with a +40G disk (total of 80G instead of 40G)

What I had to do to get my lv to extend was the following:

`fdisk /dev/xvda` delete my 3rd partition (which was the lv), delete the 2nd partition (which was the extended partition).   Create a new extended partition with the "new" full size.  Create a logical partition.   Then change it's "type" to 8e (linux lvm).   Then reboot

Once rebooted, I was able to run `pvresize /dev/xvda5` to resize my volume group to the new size, then extend the lv with all this new space: `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mylvmgroup/home`

once that finished, I was able to `xfs_growfs` my "home" to accept the new size.